# Integrating $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\text{ d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

I want to integrate $$I=\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\text{ d}x=\frac{\pi^3}{16}$$ using contour integration. I set up the function $$f(z)=\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}$$
and used a keyhole contour with a branch cut about the positive real axis[image]
The integrals about $\Gamma$ and $\gamma$ I believe both go to $0$ if I did not make any mistakes in my calculations but afaik I should be right.

The integrals about $T$ and $B$ is
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\ln^3(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{\left(\ln(x)+2\pi i\right)^3\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$ which expands and simplifies into $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\ln^3(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{\ln^3(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{6i\pi\ln^2(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{12\pi^2\ln(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\int^{0}_{\infty}\frac{8i\pi^3\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
$$\implies -6i\pi I +\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{12\pi^2\ln(x)\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{8i\pi^3\text{ d}x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$$
Since $f(z)$ has poles of order $2$ at $z=\pm i$ I use the higher order residue formula and get
$$\implies\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = i}\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z+i\right)^2}\right]=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\ln^{2}(z)\left(3i+3z-2z\ln(z)\right)}{z\left(z+i\right)^{3}}=-\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}-\frac{3i\pi^{2}}{16}$$
$$\implies\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = -i}\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}=\lim_{z\to -i}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z-i\right)^2}\right]=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\ln^{2}(z)\left(3z-3i-2z\ln(z)\right)}{z\left(z-i\right)^{3}}=-\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}+\frac{3i\pi^{2}}{16}$$
which when added and multiplied with $2\pi i$ give $-\dfrac{i\pi^4}{8}$.

Equating only imaginary parts of both sides gives
$$-6\pi I + 2\pi^4 = -\frac{\pi^4}{8}$$
$$\implies I=\frac{17\pi^3}{48}$$

---

This is obviously wrong. Plus, the real part is nonzero too so my final equation is nonsense. Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you forgot arg of $i$ and $-i$ with this branch cut.

Comment: @PelikanSH037 wait wdym by that

Comment: See the below answer, because of this branch cut so $arg(-i)=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, and $\log{(z)}=\log{|z|}+iarg(z)$.

Comment: Oh i am having a brain fart thanks lmao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue at $-i$ should be
$$\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = -i}\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^2}=\lim_{z\to -i}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z}\left[\frac{\ln^3(z)}{\left(z-i\right)^2}\right]=\lim_{z\to -i}\frac{\ln^{2}(z)\left(3z-3i-2z\ln(z)\right)}{z\left(z-i\right)^{3}}=\frac{27\pi^3}{32}+\frac{27\pi^2  i}{16}$$
where at the last step, due to the branch cut, $\ln(-i)=|-i|+i\text{arg}(-i)=\frac{3\pi i}{2}$.

Hence, equating the imaginary parts, we find
$$-6\pi I + 2\pi^4 = 2\pi\left(-\frac{\pi^3}{32}+\frac{27\pi^3}{32}\right)$$
that is
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln^2(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\,dx=I = \frac{(32-26)\pi^3}{3\cdot 32}=\frac{\pi^3}{16}.$$
Note that equating the real parts, we get
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\,dx=-\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you lol I feel so stupid defining 0<arg(z)<2pi and then not using it lmao